# Concordance Correlation Coefficient for negative correlations

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, concordance

A question regarding the [Concordance correlation coefficient (CCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_correlation_coefficient).
I would like to implement it in Python. Following the Wikipedia entry, one of the possible implementations would be

```py
import numpy as np
def ccc(x,y):
    vx, cov_xy, cov_xy, vy = np.cov(x,y, bias=True).flat
    mx, my = x.mean(), y.mean()
    return 2*cov_xy / (vx + vy + (mx-my)**2)
```

However, I have noticed that it does not behave as expected when it comes to negative correlations:

```py
>>> x = np.linspace(0,1,10)
>>> y = np.linspace(0,1,10)
>>> ccc(x,y)
1.0
>>> ccc(x,-y)
-0.16923076923076918
```

From my understanding, the CCC should be able to capture negative correlation just as well as the Pearson's r, in which case I would expect `ccc(x,-y) == -1`.

Could anyone point me to the reason I am not getting the expected value here? Is there something wrong with my implementation, or is the CCC indeed not capable of capturing such cases?

Comment: The presence of the squared mean difference in the denominator guarantees the CCC cannot attain $\pm 1$ unless the means are identical.  Have you noticed that the difference of means of `x` and `y` is zero but the difference of means of `x` and `-y` is $1$?  Consider doing your testing on an equal basis by computing `ccc(x, 1-y)` instead and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not consider getting the means right!

Comment: That's natural, because the CCC is a bizarre statistic.  In particular, to make any sense it *requires* that the two variables represent the same kind of quantity and are expressed in the same unit of measurement.  It is noteworthy that the Wikipedia article consistently describes its properties in terms of approximations to other measures of association, leading one to wonder why we wouldn't just choose an appropriate measure rather than settle for some strange approximation.